# paste into a txt file without overwriting

Tags: vbscript

hi i am trying to paste some data from a website into a txt doc, is it possible to paste on a new line without overwritting the file?
this is my code,

```js
Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
For Each window In app.Windows()
  If InStr(1, window.FullName, "iexplore", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    Set ie = window
    Exit For
  End If
Next

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("output.txt", 2, True,utf-2)
f.Write ie.Document.All.Item("resltext").innerText
f.Close
```

Comment: So you basically try to open the file in append mode ?

Comment: Then your solution is in the answer below. Try to read the docs before asking questions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Append text to text file if it already exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30478983/append-text-to-text-file-if-it-already-exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it

```js
f.WriteLine ie.Document.All.Item("resltext").innerText
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_opentextfile.asp,
it looks like if you change 
    Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("output.txt", 2, True,utf-2) 
to 
    Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("output.txt", 8, True,utf-2) 
it will append to the end of the file instead of overwrite.

Comment: yes it worked but it pastes the data on the same line instead of creating a new line

Comment: Perhaps do a second write immediately after with a newline?
write "\n"

Comment: To write a newline in VBScript, you need to use `vbCrLf`.